# Hexadecimal line numbers in listings

Tags: listings, code, line-numbering

Is it possible to introduce hexadecimal line numbers in steps of two using the `listings` package?

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle={\ttfamily\small}}
\lstset{keywordstyle={\bfseries}}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\sffamily\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[x86masm]Assembler}]
mov ax, [10]
jz 0A
add bx, [11]
dec ax
jmp 02
mov [12], bx
hlt
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve that `00`, `02`, `04`, `06`, `08`, `0A`, `0C` is printed instead of arabic line numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using packages `xintbinhex` for hexadecimal numbers, `calc` for counting by steps of 2, and renewing the `\thelstnumber` command for numbering, as indicated in the `listings` documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xintbinhex}
\usepackage{calc}

\lstset{basicstyle={\ttfamily\small}}
\lstset{keywordstyle={\bfseries}}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\sffamily\tiny}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<8 0\fi \xintDecToHex{\the\value{lstnumber}*2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[x86masm]Assembler},firstnumber=0]
mov ax, [10]
jz 0A
add bx, [11]
dec ax
jmp 02
mov [12], bx
hlt
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mixed the approaches by JPG and jfbu approaches by using `\newcommand\HexLineNum[1]{\ifnum#1 < 8 0\fi\xintDecToHex{2 * {#1}}}` and `\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny\HexLineNum}`.

Answer (score 5):

One could do this with no package and little effort using TeX arithmetic so it is bit overfill to use `xintbinhex` here but it works. But it does not provide macros to pad to a given number of hex-digits, I needed to code it here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle={\ttfamily\small}}
\lstset{keywordstyle={\bfseries}}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny}

\usepackage{xintbinhex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myHexNumber[1]{\ttfamily\tiny
                           \romannumeral\expandafter\myHexNumber@pad
                           \romannumeral0\xintdectohex{#1}.}%
% change 2 into how many hex digits are asked for with leading 0s
% (I guess 2 or 3 ...)
\def\myHexNumber@pad#1.{\xintreplicate{2-\xintLength{#1}}{0}#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[language={[x86masm]Assembler}, numberstyle=\myHexNumber]
mov ax, [10]
jz 0A
add bx, [11]
dec ax
hjmp 02
mov [12], bx
hlt
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This picture does not really prove it does work... but it does, no doubt about it! But it was done when I erroneously used `\sffamily`. Now corrected to `\ttfamily` see next image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: another method of padding is to add `256` to number to convert and then remove the leading `1`. Or to add `4096` and remove leading 1 if one wants three hex-digits. The method here will silently switch from 2 to 3 or more digits when reaching `FF` so I think it is better.

Comment: Please see my comment to JPG's answer. I think using `numberstyle` is more versatile when mixing different styles (e.g., for Assembler, Java etc.) in a single document which occurs in my case.